# Yii - Add new entry in main Config file.

Tags: php, yii

I want to add a new entry for example 'domain' to `config/main.php`. I just add it but this error is given:

```
Property "CWebApplication.domain" is not defined.
```

How can I add completely new entry to config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add to params :

```
...
'params' => array(
   'someKey' => 'someValue',
),
```

and access it like

```
$key = Yii::app()->params['someKey'];
```